# jquery - How to return focus to the same textbox

Tags: jquery, textbox

I have 2 textboxes. If the first textbox is empty it cannot proceed to the 2nd textbox when I hit tab or the user will intentionally place the focus on the 2nd textbox.

**html**

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" />
<input type="text" id="txt2" />
```

**jquery/javascript**

```
$("#txt1").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 9)  {
        if ($.trim($(this).val() == ""))
            $(this).focus();
     }
 });

if ($("#txt2").is(":focus")) {
    if ($.trim($("#txt1").val() == "")) 
         $("#txt1").focus();
}
```

Please see the this : http://jsfiddle.net/N8GAr/

I need help with this. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to do this. But I'd recommending disabling the 2nd input otherwise it will be confusing for your users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/)  function of jquery like this

```
$("#txt2").focus(function() {
        alert('abc');
        if ($.trim($("#txt1").val() == "")) 
             $("#txt1").focus();
    });
```

just see your desired result on [**Jsfiddle.net**](http://jsfiddle.net/KNEbj/3/)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$("#txt1").keydown(function (e) { 
if (e.which == 9)  {
    if ($.trim($(this).val() == ""))
        $(this).focus();
}
});
$("#txt2").focus(function(){
    if ($.trim($("#txt1").val() == "")) 
        $("#txt1").focus();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find the solution below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#txt2").focus(function(){
        if(!$("#txt1").val())
        $("#txt1").focus();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do double logic check there. For example, this code will not allow the second field to be focused if the first one it empty. You want this one, right? 
If user presses tab in the first field, it will still keep the first field focused. Will only move to the second field if the first one is not empty.

```
$("#txt2").focus(function(e){
    if (!$.trim($("#txt1").val())) {
       $("#txt1").focus();
       return false;
    }
});
```